# Retrieving/Handling Image URL From Firestore - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I need to display an image stored in firebase-firestore in the frontend of my project but I don't know how to do that. I will provide my code here:

```
const {currentUser, } = useAuth();
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await firestore.collection("users").doc(currentUser.email).get();
            setData(data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(),
            img: doc.data().userImg,})));
        };
        fetchData();
        }, []);
         return (
            <>
             <img src={data.img} alt="Avatar" class="profile" />
            </>
          )
```

[image: I have also added firestore screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
const {currentUser, } = useAuth();
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(currentUser.email).get();
            setImgUrl(response.imgUrl);
        };
        fetchData();
        }, []);
         return (
            <>
             <img src={imgUrl} alt="Avatar" class="profile" />
            </>
          )
```

Fetch the doc and then and get the imgUrl and set the value to setImgUrl state. Pass the imgUrl to the img tag.